# Displaying Console Message When Location is Turned Off outside the IOS app

Tags: react-native

"I have successfully implemented the background geolocation package within the application, and my objective is to prompt the console to display a notification when the user's location is deactivated beyond the confines of the app."

"I've done a lot of searching."